# Help to use Statistics and algebra books for community

Tags: st.statistics, schemes, textbook-recommendation, books, higher-algebra

My father has 2000 statistics and higher algebra books (schaum series etc). Need to use these for community since he passed away (India) kindly guide me

I just need to know if we can donate these books where it will be used sincerely. (Books can be shipped across india )